# Question relating to the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The question I am trying to answer is:

Suppose $f$ is analytic in the punctured disc $0 < |z| < 1$ except for poles $\{z_n\}$ where: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}z_n = 0$$

Note that $0$ is not an isolated singularity. Show that the range of $f$ in the punctured disc is dense in the complex plane.

I think I have to use a variant of the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem; possibly Picard's Big Theorem, but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there is an epsilon ball around $w$ which is disjoint from the image of $f$.  Consider $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-w}$ which is analytic except for at $z_n$ and $0$.  Since $g$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ these singularities are removable.  Hence $g$ extends to an analytic function which is zero at $z_n$ (and at $0$).  Hence $g$ is zero on a set with a limit point and so $g$ is identically zero.  But this is impossible by definition of $g$.

Comment: So it IS basically an extension of the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem with more than one singularity? Thank you!